# Ошибка Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type Select is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Выходит ошибка: **Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type Select is not JSON serializable** При наборе команды. Я сделал команду, чтобы вывадился меню, но при наборе команды выходит ошибка.
Код:

```py
from discord_components import *

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(bot)

@bot.command()
async def тест(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Тесттест', 
    components=[
    Select(
    placeholder='Test',
    options=[
    SelectOption(label='тест', value = 'тест2'), 
    SelectOption(label='тест B', value = 'тест3')]
    )
    ]
    )
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")
    await interaction.respond(content="Lol")
```

В чем ошибка? И причём тут json файлы?

Comment: А как вы бота создаете? Добавьте минимальный пример в вопрос

Comment: А так, этот пример у вас работает https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components/blob/64a9416e4c0bad77ff8f901573f168db3b59f49e/examples/basic.py#L4 ?

Comment: Смысле как создаю?

Comment: Ага, добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Тот пример, который Вы скинули, он так же не работает, ошибка та же. И я пишу код на телефоне/пк. На телефоне pydroid 3, на пк visual studio code.